# JPS command shows only JPS

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-18.04, hadoop3

[image]

I installed hadoop and tried to run it. The terminal shows that everything has been started but when i run jps command it shows only jps. I am new to ubuntu and we need to use for academics can anyone help me run it. 
I installed java using `sudo apt-get install open-jdk`
My usr/lib/jvm directory looks like this
[image]

The following are my hadoop configuration files:
[image: hdfs-env.sh]

[image: mapred-site.xml]

Comment: I don't think that your services started in the first place. You can check it by using ports. Check if your machine is listening to 50070,8090,50075 ports? And if yes, try to use this ports and see if you can get an UI for the daemon process you started.

Comment: could you  open the namenode  webpage  ,please  show your namenode & datanode logs ,

Comment: i ran sudo netstat -plnt after start-all.sh and there were no ports with the above mentioned port numbers. Also i am not getting a web page ui on entering localhost:50070 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably due to the users you are using . I can see start-all.sh with different user and jps with a different user. Run both commands with the same user

Comment: My apologies i saw only the top user .

Comment: Can you try using jps -J-Djava.io.tmpdir=/<dir>/
This <dir> hduser should have read write access